# How to maintain the order of keys while parsing JSON in groovy

Tags: java, json, parsing, groovy

I am trying to parse a big JSON file conataing a lot of keys and then after making changes to 10-12 keys i am writing back the modified content to a new text file.

The issue i am facing is that the sequence of keys change and it is necessary for me to maintain the sequence of keys.

I am using the below code to do so

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

def inputFile = new File("C:\\input\\input.json")

def InputJSON = new JsonSlurper().parseText(inputFile.text)
...
InputJSON.key1 = 'a'
InputJSON.key2 = 'b'
...
new File("C:\\output\\output.txt").write(new JsonBuilder(InputJSON).toPrettyString())
```

Please help me in writing back the modified content after parsing in order to the new text file.

Comment: If any code, in any language, is relying on the order of keys of a JSON object, then that code should be fixed, because keys of an object are not supposed to have any specific order. So, in short, you shouldn't care about the order of the keys.

Comment: @JBNizet i have came across the same suggestion but in my case i need to duplicate the input json file to 10-14 different text file with changes in some key with diffrent values in each file so that one can observe the changes easily.It has nothing to do with the code it is related to QA process automation.

Comment: Do you need to parse it as JSON or you can use string manipulation and directly make the changes?  Not sure whether `toPrettyString()` is causing the problem though.  Can you try just `toString()`?

Comment: For qa, can't they load the json into a hashmap (which also has no order) and compare maps?

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have an object Fields that you are converting to json using groovy

you would normally do this

```
new JsonBuilder(obj).toString()
```

now if you want to ensure that the order of keys in json is field2,field3,field4,field1 then you could do

```
def listOfFields = [
   "field2",
    "field3",
    "field4",
    "field1"
]

Map map = new LinkedHashMap();

listOfFields.each{  
    map[it] = obj."${it}"
}

new JsonBuilder(obj).toString()
```

this will make sure that your json has

```
{   
    "field2": "val2",
    "field3": "val3",
    "field4": "val4",
    "field1": "val1"

}
```